# How to obtain percent correct responses from the QUEST data

Tags: measurement

I'm new to analyzing QUEST data to produce psychometric functions. I am using Psignifit in Matlab for this.

I have this data:

[image]

Column #1 has stimulus contrast presented in the first or the second interval and column #2 (response) says whether the user correctly identified the interval in which it was presented. 1 is correct and 0 is wrong. With QUEST, each contrast level presented is different and there is only row for that particular contrast.

1. How do I use this data (1s and 0s) to get % correct and fit the psychometric function to that data in psignifit in Matlab?
2. Is there a way to build the psychometric function without binning the data?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What sort of shape do you expect the function to have?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to bin the data first.  Why not make the data available and see if anyone will assist?